# Copy turtle variable depending on if statement

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am building a model for a predator prey system and I am incorporating a small basic machine learning internal model in the predator.

Predators have 4 strategies (strat is the variable), at the start of the day they select a strat and at the end of each day they check if they had a successful hunt with that strat.

I have another variable that predators own called best-strat which I want to be copied from the last successful strat

my code is the following

```
to recall-hunts
  if ticks = 98 [ifelse hunt-today = 1 [set last-hunt "success"] [set last-hunt "failure"]]
end

to evaluate-hunt
  if ticks = 99 [if last-hunt = "success" [set best-strat best-strat = strat]
  if last-hunt != "success" [set strat one-of strategies]
    stop]
end

to strategy
  if ticks = 1 [ifelse best-strat = "NA" [set strat one-of strategies] [set strat strat = best-strat]] 
  stop
end
```

I want the predator to evaluate if they had a good hunt with a given strat and then select the strat which worked best for them previously, if no best strat then simply pick a random one.

strat is a variable which selects from the strategies list ("strat1" "strat2" "strat3" "strat4")

every thing is working except my code to copy the current strat into best-strat at the end of the day if a hunt was successful. At the moment it sets to "false" so something is breaking i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
[set best-strat best-strat = strat]
```

The line should be

```
[set best-strat strat]
```

To explain the error you are getting, `best-strat = strat` is a logical expression that yields `true` or `false`.  Thus `set best-strat (best-strat = strat)` (parentheses added) will set best-strat to `true` or `false`, depending on whether or not `best-strat` equals `strat`.